# how to set VSCode as Node IDE

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Mac terminal(Catalina - 10.15.5) says "Module not found" when queried about a JS file. VSCode version is 1.52.1

```
febin@Febins-MacBook-Air ~ % which node
/usr/local/bin/node
febin@Febins-MacBook-Air ~ % node -v
v14.15.3
febin@Febins-MacBook-Air ~ % npm -v
6.14.9
febin@Febins-MacBook-Air ~ % node index.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/febin/index.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}
febin@Febins-MacBook-Air ~ %
```

Comment: Apparently, the issue is with the index file that you are trying to execute and not with Node. Execute an `ls` to check if the file exists

Comment: please show your package.json, maybe you have set the type: "module" property?

Answer (score 0):

There's no `index.js` file in the directory. You need to invoke `node` from the directory where `index.js` is located or provide relative/absolute path to that file, like `node path/to/the/index.js`.

If this all new to you, I recommend reading about files and directories in Unix-like systems, commands like `cd`, `pwd` and `ls` etc.